# Django View that shows related views.py

Tags: python, django

i wanna get single product in my product list it shows error
error line is 20 in views.py if i['_id'] == pk
i cant solve this
here are my views.py and error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9vpt.jpg)

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please more clarify your problem and that too in better way, see our [tour], see how to ask questions here [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the variable **i** could be list not dict (may be i[0] is dict), that's why you're getting this error, update it accordingly